# What does an empty input's value when using POST in asp?

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

I am using asp (JScript as my language) and working with getting data from a form that is sent using POST.

Specifically, I have a text input and I want to check if it was left empty. When leaving it empty, and including `Response.Write(Request.form('opt2Dur'))` in the called page, nothing prints (doesn't print null or undefined).

My thought was that it was just an empty string so I included this: `Response.Write(Request.form('opt2Dur') === '')`, however this printed `false`.

It will print true if I use `Response.Write(Request.form('opt2Dur') == '')` (== not ===). What is the true value that I can check against using `===`? Or, in this case will it be sufficient to check with just `==`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify that you're using Classic ASP 3.0 with JScript as your language? If so, please remove the `asp.net` tag and replace it with `classic asp`.

Comment: To be honest, I am not completely sure. I was given some code from another developer and asked to replicate/improve it. If you would assume that it is classic, then I will change the tag.

Comment: If You use classic ASP (not .NET), then You don't need check form value using `===` statement, just use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

In scripting languages with "flexible" types and default values it's very easy to get confused with actual data types.

The actual type of each Request item (both QueryString and Form, it doesn't matter) is some sort of Array as it also supports more than one form element with the same name submitted to the ASP handler. It's mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as well:

> The Form collection is indexed by the names of the parameters in the request body. **The value of Request.Form(element) is an array of all the values of element that occur in the request body**.

Since the `===` also take into account type, it will return false in your case as array is not a string.

I wasn't able to find the exact actual type and reproduce it with local variable (it's not any plain array) so if you are keen on using the strict comparison operator, check the Count:

```
Response.Write(Request.Form('opt2Dur').Count === 0);
```